# Do we need the [tableless] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Just ran across the [tableless](/questions/tagged/tableless) tag and not really sure what to do about it. My first instinct is to burn it. It sounds a lot like tagging something with "not using tables" (similar to tagging with "not javascript"), which is a purely Meta use.

Designing pages without using tables isn't really something new. It's always been the way you're *supposed* to construct your HTML, people just didn't seem to care. With only 53 uses, it doesn't appear to be in any form of popular use. Should this tag just be destroyed, or does someone else see something in it that's invisible to me?

**Note:** I've already killed off the [table-less-design](/questions/tagged/table-less-design) tag, which made absolutely no sense with that hyphen in between "table" and "less" (and also only had 9 questions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've look at the questions and it does not seem useful in any way. So I suggest our friend :

[image]

I mean if people want tableless HTML solutions... they should specify it in their questions instead of tagging it.  Also, this tag doesn't seem to be related to any library or function specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the vast majority of users wouldn't blink and eye at it's demise. We've been avoiding using tables for pure layout/design purposes for a long time now (thankfully), so burning it would get my vote and probably many other people's vote too.

Surely there's a reason that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) has been locked for historical significance.

Speak to most people now and they'll likely tell you "tables are for displaying data".